# When to use a question mark for "I beg your pardon"

Tags: expressions

In writing, to mean 'Say that again please?', do I have to use '?' at the end of the sentence 'I beg your pardon'?

Comment: It could depend on how the idiom *I beg your pardon* is used. If it is a simple request for someone to repeat something the listener hasn't heard properly then a question mark would seem to be in order. However sometimes it is used as an exclamation, signifying shock at what one has heard. Teenage pupil to schoolteacher: *You are a miserable old git*. Schoolteacher *I beg your pardon!*.

Comment: I don't see any different between the first *beg your pardon* vs the second. Not sure what OP is asking.

Comment: A question mark identifies spoken intonation.  If the sentence is to be spoken with the rising intonation characteristic of a question then the question mark should be used.

Answer (score 3):

When we say "I beg your pardon?" with the tone of the question, we are doing what you described: asking for someone to repeat themselves.

> Greg did not hear the last few words of his manager's orders. "I beg your pardon?" he asked.

When we say it without the question mark, it becomes an apology—like we are saying "excuse me".

> A loud ringing disturbed the silence of the office. Greg paled, his hand going to his pocket. "I beg your pardon," he mumbled before running out of the room.